# How to extend otput of artisan serve?

Tags: laravel

I'm running this command in the console:

```
php artisan serve -vvv
```

In the browser I run this endpoint: http://127.0.0.1/health

in the console output, I have:

```
2023-08-22 08:15:19 ....................... ~ 1s
```

**Question:** how can I extend the output?

for example:
`2023-08-22 08:15:19 ...http://127.0.0.1/health.............. ~ 1s`

I expected that the verbose mode will do something like this. but nope.

Comment: I've never seen this done. Why would you want to ? I don't really look at the terminal when running the API

Comment: we want to understand what the line refers to.

for example you may have:
2023-08-22 08:16:11 ....................... ~ 1s  
2023-08-22 08:17:13 ....................... ~ 1s  
2023-08-22 08:18:19 ....................... ~ 1s  

we don't understand for what response each line

Comment: Hmm, you could add logs in your controller methods such as :         
app('log')->info("Request Captured", $request->all());

This should save inside storage->logs->laravel.log

Comment: yes. we can add logs.

but the main goal is to extend the output. 
instead of dots need to see who/what did request.